# Published Outlook calendar on WebDAV not updating on Google Calendar?

Tags: outlook, calendar, webdav

My Outlook work calendar permissions are blocked, but I would like to have my Outlook calendar updates appear on my Google calendar. I successfully published the calendar and added it to my Google calendar via URL, but the events are not updating.

I followed the instructions on these [blog](http://www.seevablog.com/install-and-configure-webdav-in-windows-iis/) [posts](http://www.seevablog.com/share-microsoft-outlook-calendar-with-other-systems/) to configure my WebDAV with Windows IIS and share my Outlook calendar to "webcal://my_ip_address:8085/My_Calendar.ics".

The file seems to be updating fine because when I load it into my Outlook app, it updates with new events. It seems the problem is importing it to Google calendar since nothing is showing up. Please help!